# Increase execution limit for Server Action in NextJS / Vercel?

Tags: next.js, vercel, server-action

I have a Server Action in NextJS14 hosted on Vercel. In the Vercel logs I can see the function is timing out:

```
Execution Duration / Limit.    15.01s / 15s (timed out)
```

I'm calling the OpenAI API which can be slow. How do I increase the time limit?

Answer (score 2):

You must apply a new max duration inside your top level page.tsx:

```
export const maxDuration = 90;

export async function Page(){ }
```

[Inside route-segment in next-js](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) docs you can find more information about it.